# how to store an any view Object array in core data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, cloudkit

I have an iOS app in which user decides the objects in his view. for example if user clicks on tag button a tag button is displayed in his view

a sample sub view

```
struct CheckBox: View {
    @State var title: String = "default"
    @State var isChecked: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: toggle)
            {
                HStack    {
                    Image(systemName:  isChecked ? "checkmark.square": "square")
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                    TextField("",text: $title)
                        
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    private func toggle()
    {
        self.isChecked = !self.isChecked
        print(self)
    }
}

struct CheckBox_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CheckBox(title: "tested",isChecked: false)
    }
}
```

now the main view

```
struct MainView: View {
        @State var vlist : [AnyView]
  
         ForEach(0..<vlist.count, id: \.self)
    { i in
        vlist[i]
    }

 Image(systemName: "checklist")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            addItem(item: "checklist")
                        }
private func addItem(item: String)
    {

        switch item
        {
        case "checklist" :
            let newCheck = AnyView(CheckBox(title: "default", isChecked: false))
            self.vlist.append(newCheck)
        default:
            break
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

now the saving part

```
     let sk = try?NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: vlist, requiringSecureCoding: false)
contextObject.skelton = (sk as NSObject? as! NSArray)
```

Here the AnyView Object array is vlist . Now I want to store this array in attribute of data model "skelton" of type transformable. tried NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver
to encode and decode but error raises

> requires that 'AnyView' conform to 'NSCoding'

Any methods to store the

> anyView

object array to core data ? later I have to push it to cloud kit

Comment: It makes no sense at all to save UI elements like views in Core Data. Save states or/and identifiers/attributes.

Comment: @vadian every user has his own checkboxes and other UI elements how should I handle that ?

Comment: Any view can be described by attributes. As I said, for example save a String or even an Enum as kind, a String for the title and a Bool for the state. Other attributes can be saved as JSON string.

Comment: You should also consider creating a model type to hold the data so that not everything is happening in the view. Perhaps do some studying of app architecture’s as MVC or MVVM to get a better understanding of how to structure your code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson contextObject.skelton is part of a row object  which I did not mention. any way thanks for the advice